# Ruby 2.5.0 warnings with Rake and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm

After installing Ruby 2.5 using RVM, and building an application using Rails5.2.0.rc1, I get warnings whenever I run rake:

```
/Users/danielkehoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: 
        warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::RUBY
/Users/danielkehoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: 
    warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
/Users/danielkehoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: 
        warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LN_SUPPORTED
```

Comment: I tried removing rvm with 'rvm implode' and reinstalling it but the problem persists.

Comment: I opened an issue for RVM: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4301

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately none of tm.'s methods worked for me.

When I looked at my global gemset, I had a version 1.1.0 of `fileutils` installed as well as the default 1.0.2

`gem uninstall fileutils` removed the 1.1.0 version and this downgrade to 1.0.2 solved the problem.

Comment: Spent 3 hours trying to nail this bug until I found this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is related to RVM. Specifically, it's because the `rake` gem is symlinked from the installed copy of ruby into the @global gemset, but `bin/rake` is not symlinked. As a result, rake tries to load copies of certain library files twice--once from the standard ruby gem tree and one from the @global gemset tree.

I've found several workarounds:

- Use `bundle exec rake`
- For Rails, use `bin/rails`
- For Rails 5+, use `rails <cmd>` (or `bin/rails`)
- Forcibly install a duplicate copy of the `rake` gem into your current gemset. This will preempt the standard + @global gemset copy of rake, thus avoiding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is related torvm.

[check the issue created for rake project](https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/248)

Comment: Yessssss... but why? And how to fix?